# Conference Data is not being Generated in Google Calendar Api : Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, google-calendar-api

try {
final serviceAccountCredentialsFile = 'assets/fineappl-test-database-59bc63f88a9e.json';
// final serviceAccountCredentialsFile = 'assets/chalogekya-3104d-a83272eadffe.json';
final credentialsJson = await services.rootBundle.loadString(serviceAccountCredentialsFile);

```
  final credentials = auth.ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(credentialsJson);

  final scopes = [calendar.CalendarApi.calendarScope];
  final client = await auth.clientViaServiceAccount(credentials, scopes);
  final calendarApi = calendar.CalendarApi(client);

  final event = calendar.Event();
  event.summary = "Meet Test";
  event.start = calendar.EventDateTime();
  event.start!.dateTime = DateTime.parse("2024-02-29T18:00:00");
  event.start!.timeZone = "Asia/Kolkata";
  event.end = calendar.EventDateTime();
  event.end!.dateTime = DateTime.parse("2024-02-29T19:00:00");
  event.end!.timeZone = "Asia/Kolkata";
  event.conferenceData = calendar.ConferenceData(
    conferenceSolution: ConferenceSolution(key: ConferenceSolutionKey(type: 'hangoutsMeet',),
    ),
    // conferenceId: "dfg-udhv-pou",
    createRequest: calendar.CreateConferenceRequest(
      requestId: 'hfiufniu84y8315izf78hue',
      conferenceSolutionKey: calendar.ConferenceSolutionKey(
        type: 'hangoutsMeet',
      ),
    ),
  );

  final createdEvent = await calendarApi.events.insert(event, 'ffffroan@gmail.com',conferenceDataVersion: 1);
  print("hecjhnucjk ${createdEvent.hangoutLink}");
  print("id ${createdEvent.id}");
  print("conferenceData ${createdEvent.conferenceData?.createRequest?.status?.statusCode}");
  print("status ${createdEvent.status}");
  print("email ${createdEvent.creator?.email}");
  return createdEvent;
} catch (error, stackTrace) {
  print('Error creating event: $error');
  print('Stack trace: $stackTrace');
  rethrow; // Rethrow the error to propagate it
}
```

I am trying to create an event in google calender using google calendar api with google meet link in that event. My event is being generated but the meet link or conference data is coming null. Guidance needed.